# MOSFET circuit in triode region

Tags: transistors, mosfet, dc

If we get complex conjugate roots from quadratic equations in the triode region what does it mean? How will the actual physical circuit behave in such a case?

[image]

Comment: What values do Rs and Rd have?

Comment: It is not important. For some values we get complex roots. What do we do then?

Comment: Generally in physics, I think if you get a complex root as an answer, it means it's not implementable in the real world.   They don't call 'em imaginary numbers for nothing!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get values without physical meaning when modelling whatever an object (including electronic circuits)...

Chances are that you are using a wrong model - e.g. the model is inapplicable in your particular use case.

Comment: Ok. I thought that way too. Just wanted to make sure. And also to learn whether we have similar simple model to use in that case